# Get number of warnings and errors from the current location list in vimscript

Tags: vimscript, location-list

I am using `ALE` as `LSP` client, and I would like to write a function to get the number of `errors` and `warnings` from the current  `location list.`

I think that a possible  solution would be to write a function that count all the lines containing the keyword `error` and to count all the lines containing the keyword `warning` in the `location list`, and to call this function with some `autocommand` that is triggers every time the location list is updated.

Is it correct?

But then, how to implement it?
Especially the part of reading from the `location list` doesn’t sound straightforward.

Comment: The last portion _is_ straightforward: see `:h :llist` or `:h getloclist()`. The part about grepping for ERROR and WARNING should work. Try writing a function.

Comment: This is good to know, but given that I am using `ALE`, I could easily fix it by using adding` ale` to the airline extension, e.g.  `let g:airline_extensions = ['ale','tabline']`

Answer (score 2):

ALE provides a function `ale#statusline#Count(buffer)` for this purpose:

```
  Given the number of a buffer which may have problems, return a |Dictionary|
  containing information about the number of problems detected by ALE. The
  following keys are supported:

  `error`         -> The number of problems with type `E` and `sub_type != 'style'`
  `warning`       -> The number of problems with type `W` and `sub_type != 'style'`
  `info`          -> The number of problems with type `I`
  `style_error`   -> The number of problems with type `E` and `sub_type == 'style'`
  `style_warning` -> The number of problems with type `W` and `sub_type == 'style'`
  `total`         -> The total number of problems.
```

Comment: This is indeed very cool! 
Many thanks for the hint!

Comment: This is absolutely good to know - I was not aware of it -  but I discovered that there is a vim-airline builtin option and I could easily get what I wanted by adding `ale` to the airline extensions, e.g. `let g:airline_extensions = ['ale','tabline']`

Comment: How to get the "buffer"' argument in order to execute that function from in the command mod, like `exe ale#statusline#Count(?)` ?

Comment: @dtrckd see `:help buffer-functions`

Comment: Still can't make it work :/ 
1) The doc says it wants a buffer number, but it actually  wants a dict.
2) So I tried this: `exe ale#statusline#Count(getbufinfo()[BUFNUMBER])`, but it still fails with an `E731: using Dictionary as a String` error.

Comment: @dtrckd Why are you using `execute`? Try `echo ale#statusline#Count(bufnr('%'))`, and see https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/3a55b757e4eafb8b33a00c0336f6ddf20ce463a7/links/vim/vimrc#L198; https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/3a55b757e4eafb8b33a00c0336f6ddf20ce463a7/links/vim/vimrc#L229

Comment: I thought a function should be executed...Yes, it works like you said. Thank you @D.BenKnoble